# I want to add a button which can load next image file and display it to canvas

Tags: python, image, function, canvas, tkinter

## I want to add a button which can load next image file and display it  to canvas. Here is the code that I have done until now. Can anyone help to add next button?

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image


root = Tk()

openfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(openfile))

wh = img.width()
ht = img.height()

w = Canvas(root, width=wh, height=ht, bg='black')
w.pack(expand = YES)
w.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image = img)
B = Button(root, text="next")
B.place(x=50, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the problem/error do you have?

Comment: Sorry for insufficient explanation. When I run my code, two windows should pop up at once. One of thing is canvas window from python library, the other thing is file dialog window to choose image file. And If I choose an image file from dialog window, that image should be displayed in canvas. And one button should be created either in canvas. Here is that I want. If I click that button, the image should be changed to the next image automatically. And this task should be happen whenever I click that button again.

Comment: `the image should be changed to the next image automatically` – what is `next image`?

Comment: There would be another bunch of image files in the same folder. for example, if there are 10 image files in the same folder, and if I choose one of files and then if I click the button, the next image should be displayed from the same folder.

Comment: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Answer (score 2):

Following script allows you to see all images in selected folder:

```
import os
import glob
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class ImageViewer(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.state('zoomed')
        self.width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        self.images = None

        img, wh, ht = self.open_file()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=wh, height=ht, bg='black')
        self.canvas.pack(expand=tk.YES)
        self.image_on_canvas = self.canvas.create_image(self.width/2, self.height/2, anchor=tk.CENTER, image=img)

        b = tk.Button(self.root, text='next', command=self.next_image)
        b.place(x=50, y=50)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def open_file(self):
        openfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title='Select image', filetypes=(('jpeg files', '*.jpg'), ('all files', '*.*')))
        self.images = glob.glob(os.path.dirname(openfile) + '/*.jpg')
        self.root.title(openfile)

        img = Image.open(openfile)
        img.thumbnail((self.width, self.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        return img, self.width, self.height

    def next_image(self):

        if not self.images:
            img, wh, ht = self.open_file()
        else:
            image = self.images.pop(0)
            self.root.title(image)
            img = Image.open(image)
            img.thumbnail((self.width, self.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.image_on_canvas, image=img)
        self.canvas.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        try:
            self.canvas.wait_visibility()
        except tk.TclError:
            pass


ImageViewer()
```

Comment: I really really appreciate your time and code. it's really great. I hope to be like you someday. it's great code. I'll teach me with yours.